pgbackrest дает ошибку INFO: restore command end: aborted with exception [072]
При попытке восстановить БД на новом хосте pgbackrest дает ошибку
INFO: restore command end: aborted with exception [072]
команда:
pgbackrest --stanza=main restore


в конфиге pgbackrest надо было убрать pg1-host
